# Como transformar uma lista que vai ser dada na entrada em uma matriz?

Tags: python, matriz

Estou tentando transformar essa lista que foi me dada na entrada em uma matriz

```
u l i o a

e a p b e

a r y l s

j i t u a

e e h u b

e u o r r

c t n e p

b i o s b
```

Esse é um dos exemplos de entrada, minha

Mas o máximo que consegui até agora foi isso, que lê somente a primeira linha

```
l = input().split()

diagrama_entrada = []

diagrama_entrada.append(l)
```

Comment: Já estudou laços de repetição?

Answer (score 0):

É possível realizar isso usando **compreensão de listas** no python.

Vou fazer uso de um exemplo hipotético por acreditar que facilitará sua compreensão:

imaginemos a seguinte lista:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

E imaginemos agora que buscamos o seguinte resultado:

```
lista_2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

A **lista_2**, uma lista de listas, representa também uma **matriz**, já que:

```
lista_2[0][0] = 1
lista_2[1][0] = 4
lista_2[2][2] = 9
```

E assim por diante...

Existem ótimos materiais na internet que destrincham esse assunto, mas para simplificar seu trabalho, observe o código abaixo:

```
# Definimos aqui a lista de entrada
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

# Definimos aqui o tamanho das linhas da matriz
size = 3

# Geramos a lista_2
lista_2 = [x[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(lista), size)]
```

Sendo que na ultima linha acontece o seguinte:

O `range(0, len(lista), size)` nos cria uma *lista* que irá iniciar no zero, terminar no 9 (comprimento de nossa lista), mas sua contagem irá ser de 3 e 3 (nosso size).

O `x[i:i+size]` está fazendo um slice de nossa lista, ou seja, cortando ela do i até o i+size. Se i for 0, ela iá cortar do 0 ao três, se i for 1, ela irá cortar do 1 ao 4 e assim por consequência.

No meio disso tudo tempo um `for loop`, que irá gerar um i (a sua direita) para cada termo na lista passada(o range, a sua esquerda).

Logo, nosso `for loop` irá correr todos os termos de `[0, 3, 6]` (*lista* gerada pelo range)e para cada um dos termos irá fatiar nossa lista de entrada, ficando com `[i[0:3], i[3:6], i[6:9]]`, que por sua sequência são:

```
i[0:3] = [1, 2, 3]
i[3:6] = [4, 5, 6]
i[6:9] = [7, 8, 9]
```

Se desejar ir mais afundo sugiro que leia sobre como trabalhar com listas e depois sobre compreensão de contêineres.